# Multiplayer Game Architecture

Tags: html, node.js, multiplayer, websocket

Can anyone recommend Articles, Books, Tutorials about this?

Maybe is (Articles, Books, Tutorials) about Multiplayer Game Architecture, Networking in HTML5, JavaScript, WebSockets, Node.js?

Comment: what is your background? What language? Online game on a webserver or Client?

Comment: I'm a beginner programmer, programming with JavaScript(using WebSocket's, HTML5 Canvas, Node.js) I'm in Networking know how to create Multi-Player Chat.
I'm need learn Server-Side and Client-Side in Game programming world.
Sorry for English language.

Comment: Not a complete answer, but this might assist you. http://codeutopia.net/blog/2012/03/10/nodejs-application-architecture-battlefield-3-web-commander/

Answer (score 4):

hey here are some guides:

http://marakana.com/training/html5/websocket_for_social_gaming.html

and here is a commented example:

http://www.startupmonkeys.com/2010/09/building-a-scrabble-mmo-in-48-hours/

was that what you were looking for?

It is definitely possible to make a multiplayer game, as i also saw a tank game based on node.js

Comment: Link for the exemple is down :(

Comment: yeah i searched for it and could not find it anywhere anymore too. Pity.

Answer (score 0):

You may find [The Definitive Guide to HTML5 WebSocket](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430247401) useful (of which I am a co-author).

In this [post](http://blog.kaazing.com/2013/02/15/the-definitive-guide-to-html5-websocket-is-now-available/) we give a quick run-down on what the book covers. The book ships (read: can be downloaded from the publisher's site) with all the [source code and a VM](http://www.apress.com/9781430247401) with a pre-configured environment for all the hands-on content, including a chat app using XMPP, a rock-paper-scissors game with pub/sub messaging, and VNC over WebSocket.